# generating notification when time matches, even without running application - ANDROID

Tags: android

In my android application, I want to generate a notification when current time matches with the time that I have retrieved from my database. And the notification should be generated even if the application is not running. For this I have done something like this, but this is not working (no notification is being generated).
I am new to android, and I have seen many examples and tutorials for solving this issue, but they did not helped. So please give Answer that what should I do for getting the desired result?

**In MainActivity.java I am doing this:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*here I am retrieving time from database*/
        String time_from_database = "20:00:00";
        if(Calendar.getInstance()==time_from_database) {
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotGen.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance(), alarmIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**this is code of NotGen.java class:**

```
public class NotGen extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setTicker("Ticker Title");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_img);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert, Click Me!");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail!");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: You need a service, if you want your alarms to survive reboots and/or inactive app.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getInstance()==time_from_database` will never work.

First, `getInstance()` is going to create a new instance, and `==` is object identity equality.

Second, `time_from_database` is a `String` (`"20:00:00"`). A `Calendar` instance will never equal that, if for no other reason than a `Calendar` is a combination of date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved it using Service. Service will running in background all the time even your application is not running.

1) Create service and register it into Manifest file.

2) Start it on application start.

3) Into service you can generating your notification when current time will matched with database time.

For service example you can see below links

http://javatechig.com/android/android-service-example

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: I have followed your instructions, but now `BroadcastReceiver` is not being called from `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Read my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078403/broadcastreciever-is-not-starting-service-in-android